# The Return stream().collect() not working when used mapping ManyToOne OneToMany

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jackson

Empresa

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@EqualsAndHashCode
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Empresa {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long codigo;
    private String razaosocial;
    private String cnpj;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "empresa")
    private Set<Pessoa> pessoas;


}
```

Pessoa

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class Pessoa {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long codigo;
    private String nome;
    private String sexo;
    private String tipoPessoa;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="codigoempresa")
    private Empresa empresa;
    private String cpf;

}
```

that method of return my data

```
@RequestMapping(path="get-all", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes="application/json")
@ResponseStatus(value=HttpStatus.OK)
public Collection<Empresa> getAll(@RequestBody String parametros){

    return repository.findAll().stream().collect(Collectors.toList());

}
```

It  Worked before i am create a OneToMany and ManyToOne mapping. I had perfectly my json return.
 Now i receive error.

StackTrace:

> at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serializeContents(CollectionSerializer.java:149)
>   ~[jackson-databind-2.8.10.jar:2.8.10]     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:112)
>   ~[jackson-databind-2.8.10.jar:2.8.10]     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:25)
>   ~[jackson-databind-2.8.10.jar:2.8.10]

This stacktrace not help much, but is only this that show me in my console eclipse.

**Edit:**
I got promptly get a print screem of console e find this:
StackOverflow Error: 
[image: erro]

Comment: Could you please copy/paste the entire stacktrace into your question ? It's for search engines.

Comment: Unfortunately not.
the stack trace that show in console, it is only this the i post.
to get o "StackOverflowError" that this image, only can with print Screen.
it disappears  the console in eclipse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting StackOverflowError. One of the reasons this can happen is because of Infinite Recursion. This is exactly what happens when Jackson tries to deserialize your class to JSON. You can break this using `@JsonIgnoreProperties`

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@EqualsAndHashCode
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Empresa {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long codigo;
    private String razaosocial;
    private String cnpj;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "empresa")
    @JsonIgnoreProperties("empresa")
    private Set<Pessoa> pessoas;
}    

@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class Pessoa {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long codigo;
    private String nome;
    private String sexo;
    private String tipoPessoa;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="codigoempresa")
    @JsonIgnoreProperties("pessoas")
    private Empresa empresa;
    private String cpf;

}
```